# How can I set the color of a docked form in a tab sheet to the correct color?

Tags: delphi, colors, themes, delphi-2007, pagecontrol

When I dock a `TForm` to a `TTabSheet` the form has a gray background color. The tab sheet on the other hand has a white background color.

It gets more complicated when theming is disabled (e.g. classic Windows theme).

With the current code the grey form has a white border which is pretty ugly.

So how do I set the form background color to the tab sheet background color? In case this doesn't work: How do I set the tab sheet background color to the forms background color?

It should work with runtime themes enabled and runtime themes disabled.

```
program Project1;

uses
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  ComCtrls;

{$R *.res}

var
  Main        : TForm;
  Sub         : TForm;
  PageControl : TPageControl;
  TabSheet    : TTabSheet;
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm, Main);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm, Sub);
  PageControl        := TPageControl.Create(Main);
  PageControl.Parent := Main;
  PageControl.Align  := alClient;
  TabSheet             := TTabSheet.Create(Main);
  TabSheet.PageControl := PageControl;
  Sub.Dock(TabSheet, TabSheet.ClientRect);
  Sub.Align := alClient;
  Sub.Show;
  // Sub.Color := clWhite; // TabSheet.Color;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: I suggest you use JvDocking in JVCL instead because it handles this much better than the native CommonControls TTabSheet + `Form.Dock/ManualDock` will ever handle it.  If you don't want user drag and drop docking and all that at runtime, then I still suggest you drop TPageControl and at least use a non-MS-common-controls Tab/page control.  It's much worse than you think. You get different behaviours on Win7/64bit than on Win7/32bit, thanks to bugs in MSCOMMONCONTROLS dlls on Win7/64 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this workaround

```
type
  TWinControlAccess = class(TWinControl)
  end;

procedure TMainForm.CreateEmbedded(FormClass: TFormClass; Parent: TWinControl);
var
  form: TForm;
begin
  form := FormClass.Create(Self);
  form.Align := alClient;
  form.BorderIcons := [];
  form.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  form.Parent := Parent;
  TWinControlAccess(form).ParentBackground := True; // <<<-
  form.Show;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Head to this *Blog post* entitled **[Theming Owner-Drawn Tabs](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/ttabcontrolex/)** by *Chris Rolliston*.

---

Quotes:

> **The problem**: say you want to customise the font colour of a tab on a
>   tab or page control.  Back in the day, this was simple — set OwnerDraw
>   to True and provide a handler for OnDrawTab that just sets the font
>   and draws the text.  With Windows themes, however, things are not so
>   simple, since setting OwnerDraw to True disables theming for the
>   control.  Not a VCL limitation as such, this merely reflects the
>   behaviour of the underlying API control, and if you think about it, it
>   makes good sense from a backwards compatibility point of view. 
>   Nonetheless, this is still an issue if you know what you want, which
>   is simply to customise a tab’s caption.  Enter, then, *TTabControlEx*
>   and *TPageControlEx*, which use the theming API to provide the proper
>   ‘look’ even when OwnerDraw is set to True.

---

At least, he might have partly solved your issues with his **TTabControlEx** and/or **TPageControlEx** components.